# flotr2 precision labels

Tags: flotr2

I just started using flotr2 and I want to have labels with many decimal numbers, for example 1.3333338.How you define that on flotr2 yaxis;

Answer (score 1):

In your `options` object you initialise the graph with, you should define the number of decimals for the axis:

```
yaxis: (
  tickDecimals: 7
}
```

Comment: That was pretty str8 forward!!Thank u for the quick response, but is there a way to force label to have more percision?For example  have a lable 1.333338 or this is done automatic by the data you provide?